# Select The minimum salary

Tags: python, database, sqlite

The below picture has 2 employees who have min salary in a staff. The problem is when I write a query for the min salary it shows me only the first employee min salary but doesn't show the 2nd employ salary

[image: picture]

```
my Query for Select min salary is:
c.execute("SELECT Staff_No,F_Name,L_Name,Position,Gender,Birth_Day,Min(Salary),Branch_NO From Staff ")
```

it shows me only the first employ min salary not the 2nd employ min salary

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is to use a non correlated subquery which finds the minimum salary, then retain all employees matching this salary:

```sql
SELECT Staff_No, F_Name, L_Name, Position, Gender, Birth_Day, Salary, Branch_NO
FROM Staff
WHERE Salary = (SELECT MIN(Salary) FROM Staff);
```

Another approach uses `RANK`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary) sal_rank
    FROM Staff
)

SELECT Staff_No, F_Name, L_Name, Position, Gender, Birth_Day, Salary, Branch_NO
FROM cte
WHERE sal_rank = 1;
```